# getting bootstrap to work in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have this jsfiddle I'm using to try to resolve an issue centering thumbnails, but I can't even get it to load up correctly and put the thumbnails side by side.

What's going on here?  Another question answered on here a few months agao said it was because the window was too small and bootsstrap was going to it's small device layout, but i full-sized the window.  The dots on the list tell me that bootstrap is not even being called although I have the box checked on the left side of jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/bVa2Z/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">

        <ul class="thumbnails">

    <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

 <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

 <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

 <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>




</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle is purposed to get your issues to us so that they can be resolved by practical application. Why are you bothered about working in fiddle? Show the issue by pasting your relevant code or a live link for which you need solution and we shall provide you ways to solve it, as you are obviously not designing for fiddle.

Comment: OP may need to get it to display correctly in the fiddle to explain the problem accurately.  Maybe....

Comment: yea, it's just a much simpler way to make it make sense. okay so it's working now at http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/bVa2Z/2/ . my problem is getting the group of thumbnails to center because it leaves an awkward space on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Bootstrap's CSS under the "external resources" tab.